# How to show download progress for MVC4 page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

How to **implement a download progress bar** or an animation gif indicating file downloading in progress on an MVC4 page. The download progress bar animation should start with click of "download" button .How to identify when the download is completed so as to hide the animation.

I am thinking of showing and hiding the below div to indicate progress

```
<div id="divLoading" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: fixed; right: 0px;
    top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #666666; z-index: 30001;
    opacity: .8; filter: alpha(opacity=70);display:none" >
    <p style="position: absolute; top: 30%; left: 45%; color: White;">
        Downloading, please wait...<img src="../../../../Content/images/ajax-dowloading.gif" />
    </p>

</div>
```

Something like the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnDownload").click(function (e) {


         }
});
```

There is also a possibility of user cancelling the download during a download operation in progress. How to detect if the user cancelled download .If the user has cancelled download ,I want to hide the div

Comment: file downloading or uploading?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `beforeSend` in ajax call to begin your animation and `success` to hide animation as follows:

```
$("#buttonId").click(function() {    
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST", //Your type
            url: "someURL" // Your URL
            data: //Your Data,
            beforeSend: function(msg){
                 // Show animation code here
            },
            success: function(msg){
                  // hide animation code here
            }
        });    
});
```

Comment: this works ,but this will keep on showing the animation in case the download is cancelled. How to identify if user cancels a download ,then I need to hide animation div ,so that the user can restart his download if he wants to

Comment: Evenif the download is completed ,its not getting into the 'success' part and the animation is showing up even after the download is completed.

Comment: You can move the hiding code into the done parameter.